# Implementing generators to populate database

Tags: python, database, generator

I can't wrap my head around generators fully, sometimes I happen to use them in a right way and sometimes I do not.

I am populating a db from a .csv file:

```
name, location
Tom, France
Doug, USA
Michael, UK
```

Here is my code:

```
def process_csv(filecsv):
    f = open(filecsv)
    f_csv = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(f_csv)
    User = namedtuple('User', headers)
    for user in f_csv:
        user = [u.strip() for u in user]
        user = User(*user)
        yield user 

def insert(cur, user): 
    u = list(user)[0]   # it's a one-elem list so take it 
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, location) VALUES(%s, %s)", 
    (u.name, u.location))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cur = cxn.cursor()
    user = process_csv(filecsv)
    insert(cur, user)
```

When run this, only the first row got inserted into the db. Can you please advise how to fix it?

Comment: We can't see how either of these functions is called. In particular, they don't seem to be connected; neither of them calls the other. How are these functions related?

Comment: Just to say that if this a one-off job, most databases have functions to import directly from CSV files. e.g. http://sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`process_csv(filecsv)` returns an iterator over users. `insert` turns the iterator into a list and explicitly takes the first item. (The comment is wrong; it's not a 1-element list.) Instead, loop over the users and insert each one:

```
def insert(cur, users): 
    for user in users:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, location) VALUES(%s, %s)", 
        (user.name, user.location))
```

Note that there are almost certainly better ways to perform this database operation. This answer only addresses the generator issue.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't so far from your goal i think,
try this :

```
def process_csv(filecsv):
    f = open(filecsv)
    f_csv = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(f_csv)
    User = namedtuple('User', headers)
    for user in f_csv:
        user = [u.strip() for u in user]
        user = User(*user)
        yield user 

def insert(cur, user): 
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, location) VALUES(%s, %s)", 
    (user.name, user.location))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cur = cxn.cursor()
    for user in process_csv():
        insert(cur,user)
```

a generateur is an iterator , so you should use it like a iterator